# Newer GCC refuses to link a project that worked with an older version

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, g++, ld

I am trying to build a project with a newer version of gcc/ld.

The relevant parts of the makefile (actual names edited) are:

```
THEIRDIR = third-party/theircomponent/$(THEIRRELEASE)/$(PLATFORM)
THEIRLIBS = $(top_srcdir)/$(THEIRDIR)/lib/theirlib.a
BLDLIBS = $(THEIRLIBS) $(OTHERLIBS)

SRCFILES = thing.cpp main.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCFILES:.cpp=.o)

TARGET = thing

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBPATHS) -o $@ $^ $(BLDLIBS)
```

Where THEIRRELEASE and PLATFORM are set in external included makefiles, and LIBPATHS is not set anywhere.

The theirlib.a is actually not the library but a text file containing `theirlib.a.1.2.3.4` (no linefeed), where theirlib.a.1.2.3.4 is the actual library, located in the same directory as theirlib.a.

This works on the build machine, which has

- gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)
- GNU ld version 2.27-43.base.el7_8.1

Unfortunately, when I try building it on a different box, with:

- gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
- GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34

It fails with The error:

```
/usr/bin/ld:/work/product/third-party/theircomponent/1.2.3.4/x86_64-redhat-linux.el7/lib/theirlib.a: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:/work/product/third-party/theircomponent/1.2.3.4/x86_64-redhat-linux.el7/lib/theirlib.a:0: syntax error
```

I assume that "treating as linker script" is the desired behaviour that makes the magic happen for the old tools (even though it did not issue any diagnostic in that case), but it does not work for the newer ones.

I do not have control over "their" component, but I can modify "our" makefile, though it should remain backwards compatible.

I tried replacing `$(top_srcdir)/$(THEIRDIR)/lib/theirlib.a` with `@$(top_srcdir)/$(THEIRDIR)/lib/theirlib.a` (not the best solution as theirlib.a may at some point be changed to be the actual library).  That got rid of the syntax error but resulted in

```
g++: error: theirlib.a.1.2.3.4: No such file or directory
```

I also tried specifying `-L /work/product/third-party/theircomponent/1.2.3.4/x86_64-redhat-linux.el7/lib` (both with `-Wl,` and directly) but it didn't help.

Is there a way to make it work as it does with the old tools, ideally by only setting the unused `LIBPATHS` variable to some flags?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04: You can use gcc-4.8 / g++-4.8 from the Ubuntu 18.04 repo. ..... Or gcc48-c++_4.8.4-2ubuntu14_amd64.deb from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing ....... Note : Lots of old software require an older gcc .

Answer (score 0):

Apparently vboxsf is to blame.  The file is supposed to be a symlink.  Oh well.